# Angular Datatable - Set static index column

Tags: angular, datatable

With [**Angular Datatable**](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) I´m trying to set column counter in datatable. With this code i can show similar that i want

```
  <tr *ngFor="let element of array;let i = index;">
                      <td>{{i+1}}</td>
```

[image: Datatable]

The problem: When i sort / search in datatable the *value* not shown as expected, reordered based on sort. I need to get static or freze column to avoid this.

I need to show a static column counter, not as a index.

So: Somebody know how i can create a *simple* static column counter?

Comment: you want to keep counter same whether you sorting or not ?

Comment: Yes, i want to keep same counter. The problem is when i sort, the counter losts order. For example, counter start with 1,2,3 and when i sort datatable based   on datetime the counter change initial order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowCallback` in `DataTables.Settings`.

```
dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {
  rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any[] | object, dataIndex: number) => {
     row.childNodes[0].textContent = String(dataIndex + 1);
  }
};
```

In your template

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions">
```